# Adding more than one input to a structural directive

Tags: angular

I've been following along with an example of how to use structural directives [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/providing_context_variables_to_directives.html) - but one thing I'd like to be-able to do would be to pass in some data from the `card.component` class into the `delay.directive.ts`. How do I do this?

```
export class DelayContext {
  /**
    - Line below demonstrated passing into an array of functions that can be called in the HTML
  */
  // constructor(private loadTime: number, private myFunc: Array<Function>) {}
  constructor(private loadTime: number, private delayService: DelayService) {}
}

@Directive({ selector: '[delay]'})
export class DelayDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<DelayContext>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

  @Input('delay')
  set delayTime(time: number) {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        let embedView = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(
          this.templateRef,
          // new DelayContext(performance.now(),[this.foo,this.bar])
          new DelayContext(performance.now(), new DelayService())
        );
        console.log(embedView);
      },
      time);
  }
}
```

I've tried defining another input parameter like so:

```
@Input('foo')
  set fooParameter(parameters) {
    console.log(parameters);
  }
```

and then attempted to pass it data in the HTML several different ways, of which none worked. Here's what I've tried:

```
 <card *delay="500 * item; let loaded = loadTime; foo: 'test'">
        <div class="main">
          <button>{{item}}</button> 
        </div>
        <div class="sub">{{loaded | number:'1.4-4'}}</div>
      </card>
```

This throws an error - `Can't bind to 'delayFoo' since it isn't a known property of 'card'` I didn't expect this error because we are in the binding parts for the `delay` directive.

Can this directive take any more input?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Gunter for answering the first part of the question. But if I define an object in the `card.component.ts` like this:

```
bar: Object = {
        val: 'Some Value'
    };
```

and then attempt to pass it to the directive:

```
<card *delay="500 * item; let loaded = loadTime; foo: bar">
```

this always prints `undefined`:

```
 @Input('delayFoo')
  set setFoo(obj) {
    console.log(obj)
  }
```

Are we outside the context of card here? Also - the complete card component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DelayService } from './delay.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'card',
    template: `
      <ng-content select=".main"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select=".sub"></ng-content>`,
    styles: [
        `
        :host {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 1rem;
      animation: fade-in 2s;
    }

    :host >>> .main {
      padding: 2rem;
      background: #e3f2fd;
      font-size: 2rem;
      text-align: center;
    }

    :host >>> .sub {
      padding: 0.4rem;
      background: #ef5350;
    }
    @keyframes fade-in {
          from { opacity: 0; }
          to   { opacity: 1; }
        }
        /* Firefox < 16 */
        @-moz-keyframes fade-in {
          from { opacity: 0; }
          to   { opacity: 1; }
        }
        /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
          from { opacity: 0; }
          to   { opacity: 1; }
        }
        `
    ]
})
export class CardComponent {
    bar: Object = {
        val: 'Some Value'
    };
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**EDIT**

A working plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tny3nJ9mDFI9hPIBNd35?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Rename it to

```
@Input('delayFoo')
```

Inputs in structural directives need to include the selector.

Comment: Thanks Gunter - it worked! I'd assume the prefix of the selector is to prevent conflicts? Any more information on this?

Comment: I expected to find something in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html. I think it was mentioned recently in a GitHub issue to get this requirement removed (not sure). I just remember running into it myself and seeing it mentioned occasionally.

Comment: Also - if I define an object in the card.componet like this: foo: Object = {bar: 'some value'} and try to pass it it prints as undefined - why is that? I'll edit the question to elaborate

Comment: Your question doesn't show what `card.component` is. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Can you please create a Plunker. They have an Angular2 TS template. Please leave out the CSS. It's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Gunter did you happen to find out what was wrong? I know you're probably busy but any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It's quite hard to keep track of SO messages :-/

Comment: I changed a few things but it wasn't necessary. `item` is a number but you print `console.log('delay', obj.foo);`, but a number doesn't have a `foo` property. Just `console.log('delay', obj);` works. Please just leave a not if this is not what you were after. https://plnkr.co/edit/pj6WLlOpcfpG4GnVpq7t?p=preview

Comment: Not (gets value from app.component and not from the card.component)

Comment: Seems I'm missing something here. So you expect `foo: bar"` to pass `bar` from `CardComponent` to `DelayDirective`?

Comment: yes - so i'd expect it to contain {
        val: 'Some Value'
    }

Comment: I think I start to understand. You expect it to be passed from `DelayContext` created within the structural directive.

Comment: This should be closer to what you want. I switched to the explicit (`<template...`) form, to make it more obvious how things look like without too much syntactic sugar https://plnkr.co/edit/cJdduoWSVZEigaNm7SbS?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129890/discussion-between-katana24-and-gunter-zochbauer).