# Where to define a function when creating dynamic content

Tags: angular

This is a follow on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934139/adding-more-than-one-input-to-a-structural-directive) I posted last week and thanks to Gunter for his help up till now. What I'm trying to achieve would be where to define a function that I can use in my dynamic content. Here's what I have so far. The `home.component.html` which makes use of the `card.component` and the `delay.directive`:

```ts
 <div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
      <template [delay]="500 * item" let-loaded="loadTime" let-events="events">
                <card [subject]="events">
            <div class="main">
              <button (click)="btnOnClickTest()">{{item}}</button> 
            </div>
            <div class="sub">{{loaded | number:'1.4-4'}}</div>
          </card>
      </template>
    </div>
```

Now the `delay.directive`

```ts
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef}  from '@angular/core'; 
import { CardComponent }                                   from './card.component';
import { Subject }                                         from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class DelayContext {
  public events: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  constructor(private loadTime: number) {}

  public btnOnClickTest() {
    console.log('Testing....')
  }
}

@Directive({ selector: '[delay]'})
export class DelayDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<DelayContext>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  public btnOnClickTest() {
    console.log('Testing....')
  }

  @Input('delay')
  set delayTime(obj) {
    console.log('delay', obj);
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        let context = new DelayContext(performance.now());
        context.events.subscribe(e => console.log(`event`, obj, e));
        let embedView = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, context);
        console.log('embedView', embedView);
      },
      obj.time);
  }

  @Input('delayFoo')
  set setFoo(obj) {
    console.log('obj', obj)
  }
}
```

Above you can see that I define a function for testing called `btnOnClickTest` which I'm trying to use where the dynamic content is inserted.

Now I'm thinking that perhaps this isn't the correct way of approaching this...

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cJdduoWSVZEigaNm7SbS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a small modification to connect the button with the observable and the subscription with the `btnOnClickTest()` method

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yiTk7vuUnuY1AWSfnaOS?p=preview)

There might be a better way. I'm not super familiar with this part of Angular2.